# Replicate Rackspace Cloud for Disaster Recovery?

Tags: web-hosting, cloud, rackspace

Does anyone know how, if possible, I can replicate a Rackspace Cloud instance X to another instance, Y, for disaster recovery? So if cloud X goes down or has a problem the website will be served from instance Y.

If replication isn't possible or the best option what is? Such as using both machines in parallel and having requested routed to one or the other - and if X goes down, Y is used.

Thanks

Ric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Load balancing will probably achieve what you want, even though the aim is to spread the load between two servers. This is available on Rackspace in beta
http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2011/02/24/rackspace-cloud-load-balancers-beta-now-available-for-all-cloud-customers/

Although they give you instructions on how to do it yourself: http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/blog/2009/11/30/simple-load-balancing-on-cloud-servers/?replytocom=9628